# about the complexity of recursive sequence

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

If i have a recursive sequence $a_1=4$ and $a_{n}=a_{n-1}^{2}-2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{M_{n}}$ where $M_n=2^n-1$

how i can calculate the complexity time of this sequence ? if we put it in the loop for n-1 iteration .

pseudocode :

S=4;
i=2;

While($i<n$,

$S=S^2-2 (\mod M_n)$

If( S==0  then Break[]);

);

im not sure that overall complexity is $O(log^3(M_n))$

Comment: What do you mean by "the complexity time" of this sequence? Also, what do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_{M_n}$? Are you computing each $a_n$ with respect to a different modulus?

Comment: $M_n=2^n-1$ is Mersenne number 
all are reduced with respect to $mod M_{n}$

Comment: So $a_n = a_{n-1}^2-2 \bmod{2^n-1}$?

Comment: yes Yuval Filmus

Comment: You still haven't explained what is "complexity time".

Comment: complexity time needed to find $a_n\equiv 0(\mod M_{n})$ in a loop using that sequence

Comment: Please edit the question to incorporate all of the clarifications and address the feedback.  We want questions to stand on their own, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Comments exist only to help you improve your question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I calculated the first few values of your sequence:
$$
4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots
$$
Indeed, $a_2 = 4^2-2 \bmod{2^2-1} = 14 \bmod{3} = 2$, and henceforward we have $a_{n-1}^2-2 = 2^2-2 = 2$ and so $a_n = 2$.